# Python how to get value from list for specific type

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print value of `entity_id` and `attribute` for type which is `String` e.g,

```
entities = [{'id': 'Room1',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'String'}, 
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346348'}, 

            {'id': 'Room2',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'Number'},
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664'}]

ngsi_type = ( 'Array', 'Boolean')
```

This is the actual definition of code where i want to print value of `id and attribute` ie, `temperature , pressure`  for `type` which is not `ngsi_type` for e.g, for `type : String` i want value of its `entity_id and attribute` to be printed

```
 def _insert_entities_of_type(self,
                              entity_type,
                              entities,
                              fiware_service=None,
                              fiware_servicepath=None):
    for e in entities:
        if e[NGSI_TYPE] != entity_type:
            msg = "Entity {} is not of type {}."
            raise ValueError(msg.format(e[NGSI_ID], entity_type))
```

Any help on it as i am new to python not able to print value of `id and attribute:temperature , pressure`  other than ngsi type with msg

Comment: This is already in code i just want to add entity_id and attribute value for specific type which is other than ngsi_type with msg.format.Thanks

Comment: To check type, python has inbuilt function called `isinstance`, for example`isinstance('abc', str)`, will return true. This will work for user defined class and its instance too. You can use it to check the instance

Comment: I see 3 `'type'` keys er inner data, I see no field `'entity_id'` (only `'id'`) and I do not see any `'attribute'` field. Please be more specific what the outputs should be. Neither of your `"type"` are `"Array"` or `"Boolean"` so currently this should print "as is" ?

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I have updated question... also attribute are `temperature , Pressure` . Also, if `type` is `String` i want it to print `id` and `attribute` with respect to its ` type :String` in `msg.format`.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were on the right track with looping over the list but you need to loop into each Dictionary to look for your type.

To iterate over the key value pairs of each :

```py
for key, value in e.items():
```

Then to check your types of nested Dictionaries you first type check it, make sure the key exists, and finally make sure it's not of type NSGI_TYPE. All together this looks like:

```py
for e in entities:
    entity_id = ""
    # put entity_id into scope for our loop

    for key, value in e.items():
    # loop over the { ... }

        if key == "id":
            entity_id = str(value)
        # keep track of id to output later

        if type(value) is dict:
            if "type" in value.keys():
            # if type isn't in the { ... } there's no point in continuing
                if value["type"] != NSGI_TYPE:
                    print(entity_id)
                    print(key, value)
                else:
                    msg = "Entity {} is type {}."
                    raise ValueError(msg.format(e[NGSI_ID], entity_type))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an attribute itself is a dict using `isinstance(obj, type)` - if it is you need to "descend" into it. You could flatten your dicts like so:

```
entities = [{'id': 'Room1',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'String'}, 
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346348'}, 

            {'id': 'Room2',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'Number'},
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664'},

            {'id': 'Room not shown due to type',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'Number'},
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Array',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664'}]

ngsi_type = ('Array', 'Boolean')

for ent in entities:
    if ent["type"] in ngsi_type:
        continue   # do not show any entities that are of type Array/Boolean
    id = ent["id"]
    for key in ent:  # check each key of the inner dict 
        if key == "id":
            continue # do not print the id

        # if dict, extract the value and print a message, else just print it
        if isinstance(ent[key], dict):
            print(f"id: {id} - attribute {key} has a value of {ent[key]['value']}")
        else:
            # remove if only interested in attribute/inner dict content
            print(f"id: {id} - attribute {key} = {ent[key]}")
    print()
```

Output:

```
id: Room1 - attribute temperature has a value of 10
id: Room1 - attribute pressure has a value of 12
id: Room1 - attribute type = Room
id: Room1 - attribute time_index = 2020-08-24T06:23:37.346348

id: Room2 - attribute temperature has a value of 10
id: Room2 - attribute pressure has a value of 12
id: Room2 - attribute type = Room
id: Room2 - attribute time_index = 2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664
```