# How to get values from dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to add value of `entity_id with attribute` for `type` which is `String`.
Below are the details of code:

```
entities =  [{'id': 'Room1',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'String'}, 
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346348'}, 

            {'id': 'Room2',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'Number'},
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Room',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664'},

            {'id': 'Room3',
             'temperature': {'value': '10', 'type': 'Number'},
             'pressure':    {'value': '12', 'type': 'Number'}, 
             'type': 'Array',
             'time_index': '2020-08-24T06:23:37.346664'}]

attr = ['temperature','pressure']

self.logger.warning(msg.format( attr, entity_id)
```

How can i add value of `id` where type is `String` with `warning msg.format` in above code..
New to python so any help on it will be great.Thanks

Comment: Please add a [minimal](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) example.

Comment: Does your problem have anything to do with this TODO in the code you pasted: `# TODO we should support type name different from NGSI types but mapping to NGSI types`?

Comment: The title of your question does not match its content at all. Please change the title to summarize what you are asking about, currently it is totally misleading. Also, please add the imports of your code, especially any 3rd party libraries that are related to this NGSI code.

Comment: Please don't expect us to write your code. You have asked a similar question one days ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63556254/python-how-to-get-value-from-list-for-specific-type . But it is not clear where are those NGSI_TYPE, TIME_INDEX_NAME variables coming from, what is the whole class doing, and why are those types so important. So I'm afraid we can't give you a meaningful answer.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath i dint get expected answer there so i asked once again with more clearer view . I think i should remove code if its not clear.Only ask with example code is only for refrence . I am asking for help not to write code. I am stuck in one problem so aksing help for that. Hope its understood

Comment: Please ask only one question and find an appropriate title. Adding or getting value is not the same. Creating a warning message is a different topic from getting a value from a dictionary. It seems to me, that you have several question in your mind and asks more of them, but it is not the way StackOverflow works. For that a forum is a better place like https://python-forum.io/ In StackOverflow you need to localize your main (and only one) problem first, than create an example that illustrates your problem. If you create a short example, you usually find the answer, before you post.

Comment: @ArpadHorvath, i have just a doubt on on how to get value from dictionary in python where some type will be 'abc' for better understanding i added warning message and little code. I created short example in previous question but dint get proper answer that will work so i ellaborated it again here. Stakoverflow is question and answer site for users and dint expect anyone to write code and nobody can without full knowledge of code .I asked my doubt its got cleared. i will keep it short in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value of a dictionary key you do the following.

```
dict = {'a':1, 'b':2}
print(dict['a'])
```

This will print the result 1

If you have a dictionary inside a dictionary then do the following

```
dict = {1: {'a': 'abc', 'b': 'xyz'}}
print(dict[1][a])
```

This will print abc

Another alternative to putting dictionaries inside dictionaries would be to make a particular key hold a tuple, look at the following example

```
dict = {'a': ('abc', 'xyz'), 'b':('qwe', 12)}

for i in dict:
    print(dict[i][1])
```

This will iterate through your dictionary and print xyz and 12. You could also give a condition to print it only if it meets a particular age by following this.

You can also iterate through your nested dictionaries if you desire that.

Depending on your need you can make it hold a dictionary or a tuple however, I think a tuple makes it easier to read and understand code (this is my preference).

Comment: Thanks for response.

`dict = {1: {'name': 'John', 'age': '27', 'gender': 'Male'},
         2: {'name': 'Marie', 'age': '22', 'gender: 'Female'}`

I want to print here, `name and gender` where `age` is '27'.... how can i do in this. Thanks

Comment: @damini chopra I have updated my answer and added some more detail.